# What Object should I use for this UDF which is supposed to look in a set of data for the values based on the column header?

Tags: excel, vba, object, user-defined-functions, lookup

Working on a Excel document in which people copy the content of a sheet in a different workbook to this document, so that my document can extract the information that is important. The problem is that the sheet that they copy doesn't always have the same amount of columns and doesn't have all the headers I need.

So I wanted to write a UDF that does the following: I put the function each column of a table, and indicate the name of the header it should be looking for in the copied data. Once it has found the header, look for the value that is written below it on the corresponding row number.

This is what I have written so far:

```
Function AkeneoFind(Req_Header As String) As Range
'Req_Header = The header that the function needs to look for
 
 
Dim Ake_Header As Range     'The range of headers in Akeneo data
Dim Row_Nr As Long          'Row number in which the function is written
Dim Ake_Column As Long      'Column number in Akeneo
Dim Ake_Cell As Range       'The Cell in Akeneo of the respective row and column
Dim Each_Ake As Range       'Each header in the Ake_Header

Set Ake_Header = Sheets("Akeneo").Range("A1:HN1")
Set Row_Nr = Application.ThisCell.Row

For Each Each_Ake In Ake_Column
    If Each_Ake = Req_Header Then
        Ake_Column = Each_Ake.Column
    End If
Next

Ake_Cell = Cell(Row_Nr, Ake_Column)
If Ake_Cell <> "" Then
    AkeneoFind = Ake_Cell
    Else
    AkeneoFind = "Error"
End If

'Insert value for header. Look among all headers in Akeneo. Once it has 
'found it, it will look up based on the row number that the Function is in 
'whether the cell is empty or not. If it isn't, then return that value.

End Function
```

Now the problem here is that there is an object missing on the first line, but it wouldn't surprise me if there are other problems, so could someone please help out?

EDIT:
Updated the UDF and now it no longer gives the error pop up. However, the value it returns is #VALUE, even if I write the correct header (with or without "").

```
Function AkeneoFind(Req_Header As String) As String
'Req_Header = The header that the function needs to look for
 
 
Dim Ake_Header As Range     'The range of headers in Akeneo Invoer
Dim Row_Nr As Long          'Row number in which the function is written
Dim Ake_Column As Long      'Column number in Akeneo Invoer
Dim Ake_Cell As Range       'The Cell in Akeneo of the respective row and column
Dim Each_Ake As Range       'Each header in the Ake_Header

Set Ake_Header = Sheets("Akeneo").Range("A1:HN1")
Row_Nr = Application.ThisCell.Row

For Each Each_Ake In Ake_Header
    If Each_Ake = Req_Header Then
        Ake_Column = Each_Ake.Column
    End If
Next

Ake_Cell = Cells(Row_Nr, Ake_Column)
If Ake_Cell <> "" Then
    AkeneoFind = Ake_Cell
    Else
    AkeneoFind = "Error"
End If

'Insert value for header. Look among all headers in Akeneo. Once it has 
'found it, it will look up based on the row number that the Function is in 
'whether the cell is empty or not. If it isn't, then return that value.

End Function
```

Comment: `Set Row_Nr = Application.ThisCell.Row` - You declare `Row_Nr` as a `Long` so you don't need to use `Set` statement, just `Row_Nr = Application.ThisCell.Row` will do (also, `Row` property returns a `Long`, not an Object)

Comment: @RaymondWu *"so you don't need to use `Set`"* is not 100% correct: You must not use `Set`.

Comment: @FunThomas - True that, you MUST not use `Set` for non-Object variable type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function AkeneoFind(Req_Header As String) As String
    'Req_Header = The header that the function needs to look for
         
    Dim Ake_Header As Range     'The range of headers in Akeneo data
    Dim Row_Nr As Long          'Row number in which the function is written
    Dim Ake_Column As Long      'Column number in Akeneo
    Dim Ake_Cell As String       'The Cell in Akeneo of the respective row and column
    Dim Each_Ake As Range       'Each header in the Ake_Header

    Set Ake_Header = Sheets("Akeneo").Range("A1:HN1")
    Row_Nr = Application.ThisCell.Row
    
    For Each Each_Ake In Ake_Header
        If Each_Ake = Req_Header Then
            Ake_Column = Each_Ake.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Ake_Cell = Sheets("Akeneo").Cells(Row_Nr, Ake_Column).Value
    
    If Ake_Cell <> vbNullString Then
        AkeneoFind = Ake_Cell
    Else
        AkeneoFind = "Error"
    End If

    'Insert value for header. Look among all headers in Akeneo. Once it has found it, it will look up based on the row number that the Function is in whether the cell is empty or not. If it isn't, then return that value.

End Function
```

Comment: With this it gives the error: 
"There are one or more circular refernces where a formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly. This might cause them to calculate incorrectly. 
Try removing or changing these references, or moving the formulas to different cells. ". 

The value that comes out of the formula also becomes 0.

Comment: I have updated the code, give a try again @AevirDenken

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much @Raymond Wu !